# Highcharts check box for y axis

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

Is it possible to add a check box for show/hide y axis in Highcharts? I've already tried a toggle button, but a check box will better meet my needs.

It should be below the chart.

My code for y axis:

```
yAxis: [ // Primary yAxis
            <%-y_axis.each do |axis|%>
              {
                labels: {
                    enabled: <%=axis.has_key?(:enabled) ? axis[:enabled] : false %>,
                    format: '<%=axis[:format]%>',
                    style: {
                        color: '<%=axis[:color]%>'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: '<%=axis[:title]%>',
                    style: {
                        color: '<%=axis[:color]%>'
                    }
                },
                opposite: <%=axis[:opposite]%>,
                min: <%=axis[:min]%>,
                maxPadding: 0
              },
            <%end%>
        ]
```

Comment: Actually I have couple y axis, so I wasn't able to make it work with toggle button. Please see my code for y axis in the description (it's a Ruby on Rails app).

Comment: you want to show hide only yAxis on click of checkbox? or want to hide complete series on checkbox checked?

Comment: I want to show/hide only all the y axes when a checkbox is checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/3sembmfo/3/)

same issue raised in highcarts user-voice 
 http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/5164818-control-axis-visibility-show-hide-toggle-axes

```
 $('#showY').click(function () {
    yVis = !yVis;
    $('#container').highcharts().yAxis[0].update({
        visible: yVis
    });
});
```

Comment: What does "0" mean in yAxis[0]? Do I need to change it if I have more than 1 y axis?

Comment: yAxis[0] means your first yAxis

Comment: What if I need to hide/show all my axes? How do I need to change $('#container').highcharts().yAxis[0].update? I will probably need <%-y_axis.each do |axis|%> .. <%end%> there too (as in the code I provided above)

Comment: use jquery to iterate over yAxis of all series , some thing like                var axis = series.yAxis,
        
    $.each(axis function (i, e) {        
            visible: yVis
        }